# Modifying Column Spans based on Item count

Tags: php, arrays, html-table, multiple-columns, calculated-columns

Ho can I modify my columns so I can add in a `colspan` if needed based on the number of items in the row?

Scenarios:

Say I have 5 Items, I need one row/4 columns, next row 1 column with colspan="4"

Say I have 6 Items, I need 1 row/4 columns, next row, 2 columns with colspan="2"

Say I have 7 Items, I need 1 row/4 columns, next row, 2 columns no colspan, + 1 column with colspan="2"

Here's my existing code:

```
        echo '<table width="100%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="5">' . PHP_EOL;

        $colSpan = 4;
        $rows = 0;
        for($i = 0; $i < $tmpCt; $i++) {
            // At column 0 you create a new row <tr>
            if($i % $colSpan == 0) {
                $rows++;
                echo "<tr>\n";
            }
            // if only 1 item in the row, need to add colspan="4", 2 items colspan="2" for 2 <td>'s, 3 items 1 @ colspan="2" + 2 <td>'s
            echo '<td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle">' . $tmpRet[$i]['sponName'] . '</td>' . PHP_EOL;

            // At column 3 you end the row </tr>
            echo $i % $colSpan == 3 ? "</tr>\n" : "";
        }
        // Say you have 5 columns, you need to create 3 empty <td> to validate your table!
        for($j = $i; $j < ($colSpan * $rows); $j++) {
            echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>\n";
        }
        // Add the final <tr>
        if(($colSpan * $rows) > $i) {
            echo "</tr>\n";
        }


        echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Could you make a image so we can better understand you ?

Comment: I have created a generalized function which will take an array and number of columns as input and do what is your requirement in the question. Check it below in my answer

Comment: Sorry.  Yes I did, he got the answer acceptance, you got the bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, that when arithmetic is useful !
What you need is to use the modulo operation at each level.

Here is my solution:

```
$tmpRet = array(
    array(1),
    array(1, 2, 3),
    array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), 
    array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    array(1, 2),
    array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
    array(),
    array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16),
    array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
);
$lencol = count($tmpRet);

echo '<table border="1" width="800px" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="5">'.PHP_EOL;
$colspan = 4;

for($i = 0; $i < $lencol; $i++) {
  $bg = 'style="background-color: #'.rand(100, 999).'"';
  $row = $tmpRet[$i];
  $lc = count($row);
  $offset = 0;

  if ($lc>$colspan) {
    $ct = floor($lc/$colspan);
    $offset = $ct * $colspan;
      $m = 0;
    for ($k = 0; $k<$ct; $k++) {
      echo '<tr '.$bg.' >';
      for ($l = 0; $l<$colspan; $l++) {
        echo '<td>'.$row[$m].'</td>';
        $m++;
      }
      echo '<tr>';
    }
  }
  $mod = $lc % $colspan;
  switch ($mod) {
    case 1:
      echo '<tr '.$bg.' ><td colspan="4">'.$row[$offset].'</td></tr>';
    break;
    case 2:
      echo '<tr '.$bg.' ><td colspan="2">'.$row[$offset].'</td><td colspan="2">'.$row[$offset+1].'</td></tr>';
    break;
    case 3:
      echo '<tr '.$bg.' ><td>'.$row[$offset].'</td><td>'.$row[$offset+1].'</td><td colspan="2">'.$row[$offset+2].'</td></tr>';
    break;
  }
}

echo '</table>';
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image: example]

Hope this helps

**EDIT:** this works only for `$colspan=4`, if you need things to be more dynamic think of replacing the switch statement with something else... maybe nested loops...

Comment: you'll have to excuse my `#dumbness`, how can I apply this to my code?

Comment: I don't know how your code and data are organized, but from the lines of codes you shared and the way you ask the question I deduced that your data are in `$tmpRet` which is an array containing other arrays. That's why I created a test array filled with numbers. Otherwise how are you data organized? I need an example and perhaps an image if this isn't the result you are looking for

Comment: thanx, it's a resultset from `mysql_fetch_array` `MYSQL_ASSOC`

Comment: This isn't very specific, anyway if this is the result you want, I believe it is simple enough to convert data/adapt code for any possible structured data

Answer (score 1):

I have created a generalized function which will take an array and number of columns as input and do what is your requirement in the question. I have tested it from my side. Please test it and let me know if you find any isues

```
<?php
function test($arr,$colspan) {
    $count = count($arr);


    $extra_elements = $count % $colspan;
    $num_of_rows=($count-$extra_elements)/$colspan;

    //print $extra_elements . " hhhhh" . $num_of_rows;
    $current_count = 0;
    print "<table>";
    for($i=0;$i<$num_of_rows;$i++) {
        print "<tr>";
        for($j=0;$j<$colspan;$j++) {
            $bg = 'style="background-color: #'.rand(100, 999).'"';
            print "<td $bg>" . $arr[$current_count] . "</td>";
            $current_count++;
        }
        print "</tr>";
    }

    if($extra_elements>0) {
        print "<tr>";
        $divisor = $colspan%$extra_elements;
        if($divisor==0 && $extra_elements!=1) {
                $last_row_span = $colspan/$extra_elements;
                while($current_count<$count) {
                    $bg = 'style="background-color: #'.rand(100, 999).'"';
                    print "<td colspan='$last_row_span' $bg>" . $arr[$current_count] . "</td>";
                    $current_count++;
                }
        }
        else {
                $j=0;
                while($current_count<$count-1) {
                    $bg = 'style="background-color: #'.rand(100, 999).'"';
                    print "<td $bg>" . $arr[$current_count] . "</td>";
                    $current_count++;
                    $j++;
                }
                $last_row_span = $colspan-$j;
                $bg = 'style="background-color: #'.rand(100, 999).'"';
                print "<td colspan='$last_row_span' $bg>" . $arr[$current_count] . "</td>";
        }       
        print "</tr>";
    }

    print "</table>";
}
$arr=array(0,1);
test($arr,4);
?>
```